# jQuery script doesn't act when changing the select option programatically (not by the user)

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers

I have this jQuery script that works fine:

```
$("select").change(function () {
          var finalPrice = 0;
          $("select option:selected").each(function () {
                if ($.cookie('descuentoGen') != null){  
                    finalPrice = Math.floor(precios[$(this).index()]*$.cookie('descuentoGen'));
                } else{
                    finalPrice = precios[$(this).index()];
                }
              });
          $("#precioFinal").text(finalPrice);
        })
        .trigger('change');
```

As you can see, it simply does some action when the user selects another option in the `select`.

Now, in a different script I'm calling this:

```
document.getElementById('selectFoods').selectedIndex = t;
```

This works as it should since it actually changes the selected option, the problem is, that why I change the selected option this way, the actions from the initial jQuery script are not executed.

Is there any way around this or will I have to duplicate the jQuery script behaviour in the other script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just try this

```
$('#selectFoods').prop('selectedIndex', t).change();
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/250/)**

Using `selectedIndex` will not trigger a change event. You've to trigger it by yourself.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll accept the answer as soon as the 10 minutes pass.. Could you please explain me (briefly is ok) why this works and my option doesn't. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think you will have to trigger the event yourself, as i could know there's no a listener that tracks every select box's selectedIndex so that when selectedIndex changes the js engine could trigger the event. that is to say, it is the default **change()** behavior that changes the selectedIndex, but not contrary.